# List appending on Python

Tags: python, list

I have a quick simple conceptual question in regards to lists and appending strings. Say for example that I have an empty list called 'Names' and I input a the name Jeff and append it to the Names list and print it out saying Jeff. Now say that I enter in a new name such as 'Mike' and append that to the list. What I want is the outcome of these 2 names being displayed in the same list, but doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong? I've been working a project that requires me to understand how to do this correctly and would love feedback.

```
go=True
while go:
    names=[]
    x=input('Write a name: ')
    names.append(x)
    print(names)
```

Comment: You're appending to the list inside a loop, and inside that loop you create the list - so every iteration is a new instance of the loop. Don't do that unless you really want to. Check out docs.python.org for info about variable scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reset `names` to be an empty list inside every loop. Move `names=[]` above the `while` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
go=True
names=[]
while go:
    x=input('Write a name: ')
    names.append(x)
    print(names)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.